# How to compile servlets from command prompt?

Tags: java, servlets, compiler-construction, classpath

I'd like to compile a very basic `servlet` from command prompt, but it is always unsuccessful and the compiler tells me the following:

```
 error: package javax.servlet does not exist.
```

I googled for the solution and I found that I need to include the `servlet.jar` libraries into my PATH.
I believe I did.
I strongly believe that the location for those libraries in my computer is:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\lib\servlet-api.jar\
```

and the end (the relevant part) of my PATH is the following:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\lib\servlet-api.jar\
```

For me, it looks ok, but it is obviously not. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Paths and classpaths are different things.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

classpath not path ... and you don't need it as an evironment variable.
You can set the classpath for javac with option -cp or -classpath (several other ways are also available).
javac uses the environment variable CLASSPATH to look for classes, that can be useful and can also be a source for hard-to-track-down-problems.

An example to compile a java file that uses a library(that is classes from outside the standard JavaSE) would be:

```
javac -classpath C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\lib\servlet-api.jar MyTestServlet.java
```

if your environmental variable CLASSPATH contains libraries you need you might want to do:

```
javac -classpath %CLASSPATH%;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\lib\servlet-api.jar MyTestServlet.java
```

(please be aware that I don't have access to a windows machine, and therefore haven't tested the idiosyncratic parts of the syntax above)
(also note that in this example "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\lib\servlet-api.jar" is a jar file and not a directory which it might be from your question on your machine)
For command line compiling on windows OS it is a good idea to have the environmental variable JAVA_HOME set correctly and the bin directory of the JDK in the PATH.

I do however suggest getting to write-compile-execute-deploy via/in an IDE for servlet development before figuring out how to do it with just the JDK from a command line.
Java Servlets are not stand-alone executable classes but needs to be deployed into for example tomcat to be tested/used.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the CLASSPATH environment variable, which can lead to unexpected behavior. Better to include an example, though, for completeness.

Comment: Agree an example, but I haven't seen a windows path in java in a decade or so. I'll try to update.

Comment: But it'd be an example of a classpath; the only difference is the separator, `;` in Windows, `:` in real OSes. And quoting around paths with spaces, although the `\` might work too--I don't really remember Windows stuff either--which is awesome :D

Comment: javac -classpath C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\lib\servlet-api.jar MyServlet.java

You don't need the "=" sign after -classpath. But it was a great answer, that saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Thanks (was a bluder, I blame that I usually send command line classpath alterations via -D)

Comment: Hey, pr123 would you please mark this answer as the accepted answer then. This is the way stackoverflow is supposed to work :p . At the end of this faq entry is instructions how to do that. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1):

First copy the servlet-api.jar file from following path

`C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.23\lib\servlet-api.jar;`

and paste it in the  bin folder of java software by following the path

`C:\java\jdk1.6\bin;`

Hope now you can successfully compile your servlet program.

Answer (score 1):

1.You can copy your javax.servlet.jar in the jdk1.6\lib folder.
2.You can go to Control Panel\System\Advanced System Properties\Environment Variables

[image]

Enter the location of the jar in the CLASSPATH variable as follows:

[image]

Then compile and run the servlet.