# Putting servlet jar in CLASSPATH in windows 8.1

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I'm trying this on cmd:

```
javac -classpath .;C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Tomcat_Apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\lib\servlet-api.jar ;C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Tomcat_Apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\mybay\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api.jar
```

I'm getting this :

> javac: invalid flag:
>   C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Tomcat_Apache\apache-tomcat-8.0.20\webapps\mybay\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api.jar
>
> Usage: javac 'options' 'source files'

I need this in order to use `extends HttpServlet` in java.
Can you help?

Comment: Remove space after servlet-api.jar

Comment: If i remove this space something else occures:
javac: no source file

Comment: And it's right javac expects file(s) to compile, what you provide it with classpath are already compiled files (jars)... So you should add in the end your source file, this extending HttpServlet...

Comment: Read this thread please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363742/how-to-compile-servlets-from-command-prompt

Comment: I don't understand.Where should I add my source file?

Comment: Remove the space after servlet-api.jar, and specify the source (the ".java" file) you want to compile.

Comment: I tried this but i'm getting the same error that i get when i try to compile my file.java in JCreator. error: cannot find symbol (extends HttpServlet)